# Length of domain wall in Ising model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ising-model

A subquestion of a homework for my statistical mechanics class this week asked of the 2d Domain wall Ising model approximation:

"Now argue that for the formation of a domain wall separating the system into two distinct regions we must have $L ≥ √N$ "
where L is the length of the domain wall and N is the lattice side length.

I do not see where there cannot exist a smaller wall. Surely this smaller the length, the more stable it is?In my understanding from reading, between a domain wall is 2 magnetised regions with opposite values. The exchange interaction between the dipoles which creates the magnetisation is a force which tends to align nearby dipoles so they point in the same direction - and so forcing adjacent dipoles to point in different directions requires energy. Therefore, a domain wall requires extra energy, called the domain wall energy, which is proportional to the area of the wall. (source: wikipedia)

So my feeling is that the limit for the size of L must come from the energy but i cannot argue any further. help?

Comment: You should look up "Peierls argument". The point is that a domain wall of length $\ell$ costs $\exp(-2\beta\ell)$, while the number of such walls (starting from a given point) only grows like $c^\ell$ for some constant $c$ (depending on the lattice). Therefore, once $\beta$ is sufficiently large, it becomes very unlikely to have a long wall. (Making this argument precise, one can actually show that, for large $\beta$, there are no walls of length larger than $K(\beta)\log N$ for some finite constant $K(\beta)$).

Comment: That being said, I have no clue why they made you assume that $L\geq\sqrt{N}$, as such a condition seems entirely irrelevant.

Comment: @YvanVelenik thanks for the tip! is c the lattice constant, or number of lattice points on the side?

yea, i have no iclue about that either..

Comment: How exactly are they defining a "distinct region"? If I have a large sqare lattice of $N$ sites and I want to cut it in half then the boundry between the 2 halves will be at least as long as one side of my lattice, that is $\sqrt{N}$. By angling my cut or adding wiggles to it I can make the boundry longer. This gives me $L \ge \sqrt{N}$. This argument does, however require you to define the phrase "separating the system into two distinct regions" in an appropriate way

Comment: d'oh..i was thinking it was an NxN lattice, i just completely misread! thank you!

Comment: The defining in an appropriate way means that you cant take a small piece ie a corner that has length less than sqrt N right? @by symmetry

Comment: @Learn4life That was my assumption

Comment: @BySymmetry could it be do do with spontaneous magnetisation? In the previous part of the question, it was mentioned that we are in T<Tc range. So this system would exhibit spontaneous magnetisation. is it true that spontaneous magnetisation only occurs for systems where total magnetisation isnt 0? so then we would have to split our system into 2 symmetric parts such that m_total=0, so L must be at least sqrt N but could aslo be sqrt 2N, for example...

Comment: @YvanVelenik also!

Comment: In the 2d Ising model with free or periodic boundary conditions (as you seem to be considering) below the critical temperature, the average magnetization is always zero by symmetry. However, typical configurations are magnetized. Geometrically, what you get is a "sea" of one the the two spin values with small "islands" of the other (small in the sense that the biggest one will have a diameter of order $\log N$). Moreover, the magnetization in a typical configuration is close to either $+m^*(\beta)$ or $-m^*(\beta)$.

Comment: @YvanVelenik right! so is it possible that by defining this sea-island set up as being completely evenly split by this domain wall , that the system would stay like this, and not tend towards either $+m∗(β)$  or $−m∗(β)$? and hence would stay with net mag = 0 ""forever""?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "stay". That would requires some dynamics. Assuming that you have such a dynamics in mind, then you have to realize that there are two possibilities: either the dynamics preserves the total magnetization (Kawasaki) or not (Glauber). In the first case, the system will keep two domains, although the long-time geometry depends on the boundary condition used (with periodic, the two domain walls will diffuse, but keep the same geometry; with free b.c., the equilibrium situation consists in a droplet in a corner of the box).

Comment: With Glauber dynamics, the domain wall will disappear after a sufficiently long time. The only way to keep the domain wall is to use "Dobrushin's boundary condition", in which half of the boundary favors $+$ spins and half $-$ spins.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94195/discussion-between-learn4life-and-yvan-velenik).